# SoundCloud oAuth Token - confused about how to sign in after initial 'connect'

Tags: php, javascript, api, soundcloud

from the docs:

> You should now store the access token in a database. Associate it with
>   the user it belongs to and use it from now on instead of sending the
>   user through the authorization flow.

On the front-end, we are using the javascript connect function, but then we want the PHP side to write some user info to the db.

I understand how to actually receive the authorization/token and it is implemented. Then I store the token in the user database next to the user's ID (that we generate). That's all fine.

But when the user re-visits our application and is logged into Soundcloud, What do I do with this token? As stated above, I should automatically log them in? What exactly is the process here? I am confused about what I have to check against.

Comment: Are you using PHP SDK?

Comment: yes, i am `require_once 'path to my soundcloud.php file';`

Comment: then you should be able to follow the examples in the docs, the next code sample after the paragraph you quoted – where "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN" is mentioned, replace it with what you've got from authorisation.

Comment: Thanks. So "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN" is related to the user that "connected"? I sort of get it, but conceptually I have a block here. All that is needed from our website/app to auth the user is this token? I'm just fumbling over where the process comes in if he/she comes to our site logged into soundcloud. They click "connect with soundcloud" - but how do we know which token to send? Sorry I'm so confused ;(

Comment: I am having the exact same issue and would really love an answer. I can easily save the acces token with the user, but when they need to sign in again, the process starts all over and I get a completely new token. Basically, I don't know who the user is until I get the token back from soundcloud. But by then, everything's reset. It's a weird catch 22.